# Lossless video compression codecs

Tags: video, codecs, compression, video-conversion

I want to create a video (bar.xxx) that is lossless from a video (foo.xxx) using `ffmpeg`. Could you please show me the parameters for such a video. The video must be playable on VLC and/or Totem. The wrapper format must be either `mp4`, `avi` or `mov`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that you have FFmpeg and the extra codecs installed.

1. Under *Xenial Xerus* this command should suffice:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra
   ```
2. Under *Trusty Tahr* this guide should be followed:

   - [FFmpeg Trac: Compilation Guide Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

Then for either Trusty or Xenial the following command will convert your input video to *lossless* H.264 in an mp4 container:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -qp 0 output.mp4
```

The file will be quite large and the video is lossless, but be aware that the value of converting to lossless depends very much on the quality of your *initial file*.

Neither Totem or vlc should have any troubles playing such a file. You could perhaps experiment a little with huffyuv:

```
-c:v huffyuv
```

but you might find that these files are *massive* for the arguably the same results as lossless H.264...

**References:**

- [FFmpeg Trac: Lossless H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264)